# Detect if promise contains data in nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router, request-promise

I have a nodejs application that returns a promise. I need help with determining if the promise "result" contains data or if its an empty array. I have tried using `Object.keys(result).length === 0` but unfortunately was unsuccessful. Any advice will do. Thanks

```js
    router.route('/user/:userCheck/').get((request, response) => {

    dboperations.getUser(request.params.userCheck).then(result => {
        if (Object.keys(result).length === 0) {
            //do something;
        } else {
            // do something
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you share a valid result of `dboperations.getUser`? This would help answering your question. Currently you are trying to test if the result is an empty object (and not an empty array)

Comment: A `getUser` method which supposedly returns *one* user if found should return either `null` or `undefined` if a user was not found. A `getUsers` method which returns a list of users that match some criteria should return an *empty array* if no users where found. This is the most idiomatic and standard way your DB methods should behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dboperations.getUser(request.params.userCheck).then(result => {
    if (result.length > 0) {
        //it has data
    } else {
        // no data
    }
})
```

Comment: I guess this would be the correct answer if `dboperations.getUser`returns an array.